# Pipe Usage In C

Tags: c, arrays, pipe

I have a question on usage pipes in C. I want have a multidimensional array in main process. This array stores 24 lines of text and a line contains 256 byte (BUFFER). Here is my code.

**BUFFER SIZE DEFINED ON TOP = 256 BYTE**

**READ_END DEFINED ON TOP = 0**

**WRITE END DEFINED ON TOP = 1**

```
            char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

            char *read_msg[100];
            char *write_msg[100];

            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


            pid_t pid;
            int fd[2];
            pid = fork();

            if (pid < 0) { // error
                fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
                return 1;
            }

            if (pid == 0) { // child process does the time consuming task

                close(fd[WRITE_END]);
                read(fd[READ_END], &read_msg, 24*BUFFER_SIZE);
                close(fd[READ_END]);

                for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
                    printf("Received string: %s\n", read_msg[i]);
                }

            }

            if (pid > 0) { // parent is responsive immediately
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
                    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
                        write_msg[i] = malloc(sizeof(buffer) + 1);
                        strcpy(write_msg[i], buffer);
                    }
                }
                close(fd[READ_END]);
                write(fd[WRITE_END], &write_msg, 24*BUFFER_SIZE);
                close(fd[WRITE_END]);
            }
        }
    }
```

In child process, i want to print these lines but it prints nothing. How can i fix it? Thanks...

## SOLUTION

```
            char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

            char read_msg[100][BUFFER_SIZE];
            char write_msg[100][BUFFER_SIZE];

            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


            pid_t pid;
            int fd[2];
```

**pipe(fd);**

```
            pid = fork();

            if (pid < 0) { // error
                fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
                return 1;
            }

            if (pid == 0) {

                close(fd[WRITE_END]);
                read(fd[READ_END], &read_msg, 24*BUFFER_SIZE);
                close(fd[READ_END]);

                for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
                    printf(read_msg[i]);
                }


            }

            if (pid > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
                    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
                        strcpy(write_msg[i], buffer);
                    }
                }
                close(fd[READ_END]);
                write(fd[WRITE_END], &write_msg, 24*BUFFER_SIZE);
                close(fd[WRITE_END]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: pipes do not exist in standard C99 or C11. There are a Unix, POSIX, or Linux thing. BTW, I don't see any call to [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) in your code above, and it should happen *before* `fork`. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: I look up it from Google and it says these things related with gcc. Am i right? I will compile with these lines i guess. gcc -std=c99 main.c -o myCat.c,  FAILED :(

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting it. My point is that you are at least lacking some *POSIX* or *Linux* tag. And don't expect us to debug your bugs. And you should compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g main.c -o myprog`. Then try [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: Using `char *read_msg[100];` is dubious; you want 100 pointers to strings?  You've not allocated any memory for the strings.  You're horribly abusing everything with `read(fd[READ_END], &read_msg, 24*BUFFER_SIZE);`.  Your writing code is equally horribly misconstructed.  You really need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]), but you need to rethink the whole set of data structures before you create the MCVE.

Comment: My array contains 256 byte for each line. I want to read 100 lines max. How can i create multidimensional array wihthout * and [] ? lines[100][256] ? :(

Comment: I SOLVED. I forgot to write pipe() function :(

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to write pipe(fd) before fork(). Thank you all :)